# Declaring a variable as global and then as local -Shadowing-

Tags: c++, global-variables

What does it mean to declare a variable as global and then re-declare it as local like this:

```
int a = 0;
int main()
{
    int a = 7;
    return 0;
}
```

I saw this example in a reference, but I don't understand it. please put into consideration that I'm a beginner at programming with C++

Comment: Notice that it is legal, but in practice very poor taste most of the time. You should almost never code like this. Read more about [scope](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scope_(computer_science)) of variables.

Comment: It's called shadowing. Use carefully as it can obfuscate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This means that in your `main` method if you use only `a`, you will refer to that one which is declared in that method, because it shadows the `global one`. To access the `global one` within `main`, you need to access via `::a`. Within other methods if you will use `a`, you will refer to that one which is `global` for every method in that file. Scopes work like this, if it doesn't find a variable, it goes and tries to find in the outer scope and so on to the global scope.

**One advice avoid from global variables**

Comment: You mean that I have two variables now?

Comment: @ibrahim.fathy yes you have two different variables. In `main` the local one shadows the global variable. For more see the answer

Comment: Thanks a lot, I understood it very well after the editing

Answer (score 1):

You need to understand Scope of a variable. A variable defined within a method/curly braces is valid as long as you are referencing it within that curly braces.
That said, in your code, to access the local "a", you use it directly & to use the global "a" (defined outside main()), prefix with the scope resolution operator (::a)

But, avoid a scenario like this. Give unique names.